# Is there something like "New Relic" for Perl apps?

Tags: performance, perl, monitoring, newrelic

We have successfully migrated all of our PHP and Ruby apps to use New Relic RPM both for Application performance measurements and server monitoring. We are very please with results, which have enabled us to improve the overall performance of the platfrom numeral times. We still have a lot of Perl applications which we need to support for legacy purposes, but in comparison to our New Relic powred apps we are completely blind to whats happening inside the apps and in peak hours. **Is there something like "New Relic" for Perl apps?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Relic has recently added [Server Monitoring](http://newrelic.com/docs/server/new-relic-for-server-monitoring) and [Python](http://newrelic.com/docs/python/new-relic-for-python) support. At this time we have no firm plans to add Perl support.

Answer (score 0):

There is an announcement from new relic, that they have partnered with ActiveState , and there is beta support for perl available from new-rewlic, so yes, there is something like new-relic for perl apps, its new-relic (I merely read the announcement, don't know the details)

Comment: The Perl support is in the ActiveState Stackato platform, not New Relic.